# Javascript promise.all axios request not working correctly

Tags: javascript, axios

I am trying to make a bunch of axios get calls with this code:

```
console.log("getting here")
const promises = Data?.stuff.map(async(id: any) => {
      axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/stuff/' + id)
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response.data)
          return response.data;
        });
      const tempLesson: any = await Promise.all(promises);
      console.log("never getting here")
```

but it does not execute until the end. Whats the problem?

Comment: I have no idea what “but it does not execute until the end” means

Comment: This looks like a couple of typos (improperly nested brackets; no return statement).

Comment: I meant console.log("never getting here") as a marker for until the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Promise.all(promises) should be awaited outside of the .map() function. What Promise.all() does is it takes an array of promises (in your case, an array of Axios requests) and only resolves when all the promises in the array have resolved, or one has rejected.

so, if you want to do it:

```
const promises = Data?.stuff.map((id: any) => {
    return axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/stuff/' + id)
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response.data);
          return response.data;
        });
});
    
Promise.all(promises)
    .then((results) => {
        console.log("All promises resolved");
        console.log(results);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log("A promise rejected with error", error);
    });
```

That's all.

Comment: okay the return was missing and the closing brackets were at the wrong position

Answer (score 0):

Your code are missing return statement and closing brackets

Your previous code should not compile. I don't know how the first `console.log` can run.

```
console.log("getting here")
const promises = Data?.stuff.map((id: any) => { // Removed async
    // Missing return statement
    return axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/stuff/' + id)
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response.data)
            
            return response.data;
        })
}) // Missing }) here

const tempLesson: any = await Promise.all(promises);
console.log("getting here")
```